# OpenMP For Loop Ranges

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'd like to use OpenMP to parallelise operations on a 2d grid where each thread will work with a subsection of the grid.

Imagine a function `f(lower,upper,grid)` which will process a subsection, given its lower and upper bounds (assume that lower and upper refer to one of the grid's axes).

The question I have is whether it is possible to call `f` without explicitly calculating `lower` and `upper`?

For instance, if I have a for loop, OpenMP will automagically divide the loop between threads. Is there a way to get OpenMP to divide up a range and allot chunks of the range to `f`?

Thanks!

**Update:**

To clarify, if I had a for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
```

OpenMP would divide up the for loop. What I would like to know is akin to knowing how the for loop was divided.

Comment: So you're asking OpenMP to dynamically schedule a 2D workset?

Comment: The 2D data will involve a number of complicated calculations, so a simple application of `for` (with `collapse`) would not be feasible. I would like OpenMP to dynamically parcel out `lower` and `upper` bounds of a loop in such a way that I can see what those bounds are.

Comment: I don't see how OpenMP is supposed to "figure out" what your range is (I can't figure it out either...)? At some point, you need to give a range of some sort.

Comment: Perhaps the updated question will help, @Mystical?

Comment: You won't know how OpenMP will divide it up. And that would definitely be dependent on the scheduling. If your code depends on how it's divided up, then you probably need to rethink your design.

Comment: you want to chunk the loop?  `schedule(static,10)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reasonably confident that the answer to your question is no.  I think that you will have to write code such as

```
f(lower(omp_get_thread_num()),upper(omp_get_thread_num()),grid)
```

where `upper()` and `lower()` are now functions which do the domain decomposition you want and which take the thread id as an input argument.

I leave it up to you to determine whether making OpenMP conform to your way of working, or adapting your way of working to OpenMP (which would mean in this case, letting OpenMP divide loop iterations across the threads) is better in whatever sense(s) matter to you.

Comment: Alas, I'm afraid you may be right that this is the only way. I think in this instance the OpenMP paradigm isn't well-suited to my application. I'm exploring TBB as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `omp task` depending how big each task is (heavier overhead than `parallel for`

Comment: It's unclear how `omp task` relates to dynamically allocating chunks of a range. Perhaps you did not understand the question. The comments may help clarify.